# Array splitting based on value

Tags: javascript, lodash

How could I split an array by value like this:

`[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]` =>
 `[[0, 1, 2], [0], [0], [0, 1], [0]]`?

I'm using lodash documentary, but kinda out of ideas for now. Is there any way to do this with `_.groupBy`? 
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Split based on consecutivity?

Comment: Is there a pattern that you want it to be split on?

Comment: @AndrewLi it do not seem consecutivity, it appears that you have to split whenever you encounter a 0 to me. Otherwise the first result element should be `[0, 1, 2, 0]`

Comment: @Eineki No, 2 doesn't come after 0 consecutively...

Comment: Is this one `[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1]` a valid input ?

Comment: @AndrewLi I misunderstood cosecutivity as two consecutive equal values not as a sequence of consecutive values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use native JavaScrip [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=example) method.

```js
var data = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  last;

var res = data.reduce(function(arr, v) {
  // check the difference between last value and current 
  // value is 1
  if (v - last == 1)
    // if 1 then push the value into the last array element
    arr[arr.length - 1].push(v)
  else
    // else push it as a new array element
    arr.push([v]);
  // update the last element value
  last = v;
  // return the array refernece
  return arr;
  // set initial value as empty array
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is succinct solution in ES2015 (formerly ES6).

```js
const newArray = [];

[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0].forEach(item => item === 0 ?
    newArray.push([0]) :
    newArray[newArray.length - 1].push(item)
);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a new array for every found zero value, otherwise append to the last array in the result set.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
    if (a) {
        r[r.length - 1].push(a);
    } else {
        r.push([a]);
    }
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to start a new array when you encounter a zero you can resort to
this code, hope it is not appear as vodoo programming.

```
var x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];

x.join("")            /* convert the array to a string */
 .match(/(0[^0]*)/g)   /* use a regex to split the string 
                         into sequences starting with a zero
                         and running until you encounter 
                         another zero */
 .map(x=>x.split("")) /* get back the array splitting the 
                         string chars one by one */
```

I assume that the array elements are just a digit long and that 0 is the start of every sub array.

Removing the one digit assumption would resort to this code:

```
var x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 12, 0, 0, 1, 0];
var the_regexp = /0(,[1-9]\d*)*/g;

x.join(",")             /* convert the array to a comma separated  
                           string */
 .match(the_regexp)     /* this regex is slightly different from 
                           the previous one (see the note)  */
 .map(x=>x.split(","))  /* recreate the array */
```

In this solution we separate the array elements with a comma, Let's examine the regEx:

`/0` means that every sub array starts with a 0, `/` is the beginning of the match

`,[1-9]\d*` this sub pattern match an the integer if it has a comma in front; the first digit cannot be 0, the other, optional, digits do not have this limitation. Thus we match **,1** or **,200** or **,9** or **,549302387439209**.

We have to include in the subarray all the consecutive non zero number we find `(,[1-9]\d*)*` maybe none hence the second `*`.

`/g' closes the RegExp. The g indicates we want all the matches and not just the first one.

If you prefer an oneliner:

```
x.join(",").match(/0(,[1-9]\d*)*/g).map(x=>x.split(','));
```

or, if you prefer the pre ECMA2015 function expression syntax:

```
x.join(",").match(/0(,[1-9]\d*)*/g).map(function(x){return x.split(',');});
```