# How can I create a new array in the array value with the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get a test logic to create a new array in this array using javascript

```
let a = ["header", "question", "question","header","question"]
```

and the result I want is

```
result = [
   ["header", "question", "question"],
   ["header", "question"]
]
```

how the right way to solve it

Comment: Your result isn’t valid JavaScript. Does your array just consist of strings saying “header” and “question”? What does an example of your actual data look like? Separating runs of items starting with `"header"` can be done with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: `{}` is used for object in JS. Your result is not array of array. Array uses `[]`.

Comment: @user4642212 Yes that is the kind of problem I support, the wrong one being 2 every time it meets the "header"

Comment: @HassanMonjezi soory, i've edit my question

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+separate+array+on+value) of [Array splitting based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44705809/4642212). I’m sure you’ll be able to adapt the conditions to your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer only works for that particular example. Here is what you need to do it for any example of that particular pattern:

```js
const array = ['header', 'question', 'question', 'header', 'question'];

let result = [[]];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  result[result.length - 1].push(array[i]);
  if (array[i] === 'question' && array[i + 1] === 'header') {
    result.push([]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```