# How to slice the array elements between the stars

Tags: javascript

I need help for y problem, assume the following array:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,"*" , 4, "*" , 7 , 8 ,9 ,"*", "10","11", "*", "12" , "*"];
```

I want to have an output like this:
first array `[1,2,3]`, second array `[4]`, third array `[7,8,9]` and so on.

I can find all the `*` with filter but after that I can slice just with `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to get the first and the last `*.indexOf(filteredElement,2)` I can't perform a search for `*` after specific number, because the user input of the `*` can be different.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried / are working with please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting array based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018407/splitting-array-based-on-values)

Comment: Hello stuart.Thanks for your reply.   let arr = [1,2,3,"*" , 4, "*" , 7 , 8 ,9 ,"*", 10,11, "*", 12 , "*"];

let filtering = arr.filter(a => a == "*");

let star0 = arr.indexOf(filtering[0])
let star1 = arr.indexOf(filtering[1])
let star2 = arr.indexOf(filtering[2])

console.log(star2) this is the code i've tried

Comment: @Code - the input array has small Syntax Error - near "12 you forgot close quote - please update your question

Answer (score 6):

**You can do it like this with reduce.**

Use a `temp` variable keep on pushing value into it until you don't find a `*`, as soon as you find a `*` push this `temp` variable into `output array` and reset `temp` variable.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,"*" , 4, "*" , 7 , 8 ,9 ,"*", 10,11, "*", 12 , "*"];
let temp = []
let op = arr.reduce((o,c)=>{
  if(c !== '*'){
    temp.push(c)
  } else {
   if(temp.length){
    o.push(temp);
}
    temp=[];
  }
  return o;
},[])
console.log(op)
```

Comment: What about if the array is `[1,2,3,"4",""]`? I updated your answer for exact OP question.

Comment: Great job! Came up with the exact same solution, but you've been faster

Comment: @Code Maniac  Thank you very much sir. but what if let arr = ["1","2","3","*" , 4, "*" , 7 , 8 ,9 ,"*", 10,11, "*", 12 , "*"];  how this problem can be solved when the number is in string?

Comment: @Code in the updated one it is checking for `*` not for number.

Comment: This it will not work for consecutive `*` characters, such as `["*",1,2,"*",7,8,9,"*","*",12,"*"]`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `slice` method in combination with `while` *loop* statement.

```js
function split_array(arr){
  let finalArr = [];
  i = 0;
  while(i < arr.length){
    j = i;
    
    while(arr[j] != "*"){ //find the sequence's end position.
      j++;
    }
    
    if(i!=j) //treat the case when first array item is *
      finalArr.push(arr.slice(i,j));
    
    while(arr[j] == "*"){ //skip consecutive * characters
      j++;
    }
    
    i = j;
  }
  return finalArr;
}
console.log(split_array([1,2,3,"*" , 4, "*" , 7 , 8 ,9 ,"*", 10,11, "*", 12 , "*"]));
console.log(split_array(["*",1,2,"*",7,8,9,"*","*",12,"*"]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps,

```
arr
    .join('|')
    .split('*')
    .filter((d) => d)
    .map((d) => d.split('|')
    .filter((d) => d));
```

Comment: Nice! :) It converts the numbers to strings obviously, but that's pretty easy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution could be to treat the array as a string and match with a regex.

So you match everything but the stars, creating the groupings, and then create you final array with the numbers.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, "*", 4, "*", 7, 8, 9, "*", 10, 11, "*", 12, "*"];

const res = arr.toString()
                .match(/[^*]+/g)
                .map(v => v.split(',')
                           .filter(v => v)
                           .map(v => +v));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility with `forEach` and a bit of filtering:

```js
const splitOnAsterisk = (arr) => {
  /* create an array to hold results with an initial empty child array */
  let result = [[]];
  /* create a new empty array in the result if current element is an asterisk,
     otherwise push to the last array in result… */
  arr.forEach(v =>
    v === "*"
    ? result.push([])
    : result[result.length - 1].push(v)
  );
  /* filter out empty arrays (if the first/last element was an asterisk
     or if there were two or more consecutive asterisks)
     [1, 2, "*", 3, "*"]
     ["*", 1, "*", 2, "*"]
     [1, 2, "*", "*", 3] etc…
  */
  return result.filter(a => a.length > 0);
}

console.log(splitOnAsterisk([1,2,3,"*",4,"*",7,8,9,"*",10,11,"*",12,"*"]))
console.log(splitOnAsterisk(["*",1,2,"*",7,8,9,"*","*",12,"*"]))
console.log(splitOnAsterisk(["*",1,"*","*",7,8,9,"*","*","*"]))
```

This can of course be generalised if you need so:

```js
const splitArray = (arr, separator) => {
  let result = [[]];
  arr.forEach(v =>
    v === separator
    ? result.push([])
    : result[result.length - 1].push(v)
  );
  return result.filter(a => a.length > 0);
}

console.log(splitArray(["❤", "", "", "", "", ""], ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Magic (explanation in snippet)</sub>

```
((r=[],i=0)=>(arr.map(x=>x=="*"?i++:(r[i]=r[i]||[]).push(x)),r))();
```

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,"*" , 4, "*" , 7 , 8 ,9 ,"*", "10","11", "*", "12" , "*"];

let out = ((r=[],i=0)=>(   arr.map(x=> x=="*" ? i++ : (r[i]=r[i]||[]).push(x))   ,r))();

console.log(JSON.stringify(out));

// Explanation - we use arrow function to init two variables:
// r=[] and i=0
// then we use arr.map to iterate and check x=="*" if no
// then we put value to r[i], if yes then we increase i and ommit value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalised function to partition an array. Similar to filter, it uses a callback, making it quite versatile.

```
const partitionArray = (arr, separatorTest) => {
  const output = [];
  let curr = []; // keep track of the current partition

  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (separatorTest(el)) { // if we hit a partition split point
      output.push(curr); // push the partition to the output
      curr = []; // and set the current partition to an empty array for the next partition
    }
    else {
      curr.push(el); // add the current element to the partition
    }
  });

  return output;
}

// usage:
const arr = [1,2,3,'*',4,'*',7,8,9,'*',10,11,'*',12,'*'];
const splitArr = partitionArray(arr, el => el == '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'm going with another solution to this problem using the array [splice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method. The idea here is to use a `while` loop and on each loop get an array of the elements that are before the next `token` separator. The `splice()` method using on this way will remove elements from the original array, so we can use the `length` of the array as an stop condition. Note also, that the number of loops required to finish is equal to the number of tokens separators you have into the original array.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, "*", 4, "*", 7, 8, 9, "*", "10", "11", "*", "12", "*"];
let result = [];
let token = "*";
let loopCounter = 0;

while (arr.length > 0)
{
    // Remove all elements from original array until find first token.
    // Push the removed array of elements inside the result.

    result.push(arr.splice(0, arr.indexOf(token)));

    // Remove a token separator from the array.

    arr.shift();
    loopCounter++;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(loopCounter);
```